# Change SHA1 Certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-webview, android-service

I've build my first application with an onlime website named appsgeyser. That application was based on webview. But now I have learned android studio amd want to build again with more customizations.
I've create new application with same package with when I upload it says thst SHA1 certificate is different of current upload then previously uploaded app.

How should I edit or change SHA1 certificate. I need to edit this app because this app is earning me plenty of money but users aren't satisfied.

Comment: Just to re-confirm once by upload do you mean to say uploading on Google Play Store or installing on device which already has your previous app installed.

Comment: I've uploaded one app. It got 20K+ installs. And now i want upload the android studio version of app. @mayankBhatnagar

Comment: @ Vikram Please check my answer I just posted

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Upload statement what your mentioned in the question I would summarize this as follow:

**Things to remember while uploading an update on Google Play Store**

1. Make sure that package name of your app and existing app on the playstore should exactly be same.
2. Don't forget to increment android:versionName and android:versionCode because these are the ones using which Google Play store analyses that this apk is an update to an existing one.
3. Most important is your APK file should be signed with the same private key which you used to sign the existing one on Google play store.

**Note : If Package Name and Signing Certificate do not match with the existing one on Play Store, then you won't be allowed to uplaod that APK as it will be considered as new application rather than an update.**

This is why you are seeing **SHA1 certificate is different of current upload then previously uploaded app error**.